# Error Report - There has been an error processing your request

Tags: error, reports, server-setup

After moving site to local server, getting the following error on frontend:

```
There has been an error processing your request
```

This is what I'm getting in reports:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.local/store/var/report/1260889028470 ; exit;
users-iMac-3:~ user$ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.local/store/var/report/1260889028470 ; exit;
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.local/store/var/report/1260889028470: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.local/store/var/report/1260889028470: line 21: `#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/store/tools-and-supplies.html";s:11:"script_name";s:16:"/store/index.php";}'
```

Any idea what the issue and/or resolution is? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I was able to resolve by removing an additional and alternatively named `local.xml` (`OFFlocal.xml`) file that I had in same dir. I had one for local server and one for live server.  Just used same `local.xml` and commented unused db credentials accordingly.

Comment: Can you remove your local.xml and let setup generate a new one? Or can you copy the local.xml from your live site and re-edit it?

Comment: Still getting error when removing file and yes, I've already tried to copy the local.xml from live site. Db credentials are configured accordingly.

Comment: What is the error you are getting from the error report?

Comment: I have resolved issue. See original posting for answer. @brentwpeterson, the report is above in my original discussion posting.

Comment: Can you post your answer and then accept it so it closes out this post? We can also learn from the answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I was able to resolve by removing an additional and alternatively named `local.xml` (`OFFlocal.xml`) file that I had in same dir. I had one for local server and one for live server. Just used same `local.xml` and commented unused db credentials accordingly.